# When would i use a self referential column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys, constraints, primary-key

```
CREATE TABLE sometbl 
(
    id INT primary key, 
    foreign key(id) references sometbl(id)
);
```

This (referencing to self) works in SQL Server 2017. I'm wondering what could be the use case of such a constraint?

Because it allows me to insert or delete anything.

Feel free to use any schema as an example.

Comment: The fact that some possibility exists doesn't imply it would always make sense :)

Comment: @RogerWolf I know. But if there is any , i'd like to know :)

Comment: @RogerWolf add you comment as answer \m/

Answer (score 1):

You may have an example of a company where employees may be referred by another existing employee!

You may create a table having columns, roughly, as follows:

```
EmpID not null int,
FirstName varchar(100),
...
...
RefEmpID null int
```

In such cases, you may use self join to extract records.

There are many examples, where you earn money on referral!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a table `Employee` (empid int, empname varchar, empid manager references Employee(empid)).

The third column references a manager of the employee associated with an `empid`. Managers are also employees and have their own record in the table. So, we can use **self joins** in this case to obtain a query like "who is the manager of this particular employee or this set of employee".

The top-most managers would have the last column `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL allows a column to have primary key constraint that is foreign key which is refering to another table's primary key.

So it allows primary key and foreign key constraints together on the same column.

You kept primary key constraint on it and when you put foreign key constraint on it, it only checks whether the column which it is refering to is a primary or unique column (i.e. whether it is having (clustered/nonclusterd, unique index on that column or not)

Answer (score 0):

@RogerWolf is probably right on this.
he commented, "The fact that some possibility exists doesn't imply it would always make sense :) "